Why is This White Line Between Two Horizontal PDFs?
The forthcoming question is motivated in part by the question asked here: Why is this white line between the two vertical boxes?
Consider the following code which produces a vertical strip (and call, say, the PDF it creates, Vertical_Strip.pdf):
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,top=0in,bottom=0in,right=0in,paperwidth=0.125in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagecolor{blue!65!black}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\par 
\end{document}

with output:

Now, consider the next set of code which is intended to horizontally attach the PDF generated by the above to itself:
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,top=0in,bottom=0in,right=0in,paperwidth=0.25in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\paperwidth=1in \paperheight=9in

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
    
\includegraphics{Vertical_Strip.pdf}\includegraphics{Vertical_Strip.pdf}
    
\end{document}

But alas, it appears that the output is not perfect:

QUESTION: Why is there a little white strip appearing between the two blue strips? (I magnified the output to 100%.) The commands \offinterlineskip and \nointerlineskip were mentioned in the answers provided in the above link for a particular vertical concatenation. Is there, perhaps, analogous command(s) for the horizontal case considered here.
Remark: If instead of the PDF output from above, I used some example images included in the graphicx package, then the second set of code should work fine. It is when PDFs are called in that I have run into the described problem.
Thank you.

your first document does not produce a pdf.

If I modify the first document to actually get a pdf, then the line in the second document comes and goes while playing with the zoom, which makes me think this is a viewer issue

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz By a viewer issue, do you mean that the thin white line is not really there but only appears to me to be there because of the viewer I am using?

@UlrikeFischer Is there a line(s) of code that I should have added which would produce the PDF? On my end, I put the code in a folder and when I compiled it, a PDF was automatically produced upon which the second set of code invoked it? I would be grateful if you would tell me what I should have done so that I don't make the same mistake in the future. Many thanks.

@DDS That's a possibility.

you would need a \mbox{} or something like this.

@UlrikeFischer O.K. Thank you.

I would make the strip slightly wider and overlap them to avoid this kind of issue and eliminate any doubts, similar to the vertical case you asked about.

You are specifying two coloured pannels that are conceptually adjacent. The pdf viewer has to render the PDF displaying it on a fixed pixel grid depending on the current zoom levels, the physical attributes of the screen and other issues. It can happen that one panel snaps to a pixel boundary one way and the next snaps the other, leaving a visible line. Or even if it is not a complete pixel gap the artifacts of the rendering of color boundaries can still leave visible effect down the join. It is highly dependent on the pdf viewer and screen technology used.
If you have control over the generation it's better to detect such adjacent panels and fill a single combined region rather than have adjacent same-color regions. (colortbl table cell backgrounds suffer from this, and it's not really fixable without completely rewriting the mechanism used, which is why newer packages like nicetabular which can colour a row as a single panel, can avoid many of the issues).
Failing that, as long as the color used is not opaque, you can slightly overlap the panels so the join does not show.

Thank you for this answer; so if I am interpreting you correctly---is it safe to infer that there is indeed a slight white gap (not just a mirage I am seeing from my viewer) which is correctable if, say, I shift the left or right hand image 1pt (perhaps) in the appropriate direction? If so, recalling a question I asked a little while back, I probably should use (I'm thinking) \hspace*{-1pt} as opposed to either \hskip -1pt or \hspace{-1pt}.

@DDS no it's unlike the vertical case where tex is inserting 1pt space (because you don't normally want lines of text to touch) the panels are adjacent with no space between them but a space may appear due to rendering artifacts (or "mirage" If you prefer to call it that) some viewers are better at avoinding this than others. 1pt is far more than you need as an overlap

Sounds good. Many thanks.
